# Filter data from local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have few datas stored in local storage as array of objects, like

```
[{"id":0,"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","email":"test@test.com"},
{"id":1,"firstname":"demo","lastname":"demo","email":"demo@demo.com"}];
```

I want to display the data of user logged in, in the text box. When I am writing localStorage.getItem('key_users'), its showing me details of all users, but how to get detail of a user of a particular index?

Answer (score 4):

As a function

```
function getUserById(id) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')).filter(users => users.id === id)
}

getUserById(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy: deserialize local storage's item using `JSON.parse`:

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_users'));
var user0 = users[0];
```